# sql query with avg price per day and group by day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got this table

```
+------+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| Name |       Time       | LowPrice  | HighPrice |
+------+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| #AAA | 12/13/2021 17:12 |    383.12 |     393.9 |
| #BBB | 12/13/2021 17:13 |   1110.34 |    1114.1 |
| #AAA | 12/13/2021 17:13 |    384.15 |     399.2 |
| #BBB | 12/13/2021 17:14 |   1112.34 |    1119.1 |
+------+------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

and this query:

```
SELECT "Name", "Time", "LowPrice", "HighPrice"
FROM rp_prices
WHERE "Time" > NOW() - INTERVAL '10 day';
```

I need to get only one price, with avg I think, and grouped by day, something like this

```
+------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| Name |    Time     | LowPrice  | HighPrice |
+------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| #AAA | 12/13/2021  |    383.12 |     393.9 |
| #BBB | 12/13/2021  |   1110.34 |    1114.1 |
+------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Check https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT "Name", date_trunc('day', "Time"), avg("LowPrice"), avg("HighPrice")
  FROM rp_prices
 WHERE "Time" > now() - interval '10 day'
 GROUP BY "Name", date_trunc('day', "Time")
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT "Name", "Time", 
       min("LowPrice") as min_lp, 
       max("HighPrice") as max_hp, 
       avg("LowPrice") as avg_lp,
       avg("HighPrice") as avg_hp,
       avg(("HighPrice" - "LowPrice")/2) as avg_middle 
FROM rp_prices
where "Time" > now() - interval '10 day'
group by "Name", "Time";
```

might give you the answer you are looking for.
It is allowed to use functions in the Group By clause. You can use those if the column "Time" has a higher precision than days